# The common element between a row and a column in a python dataframe

Tags: python, dataframe

I have two dataframes. The FIRST one, shown below, has three columns.

```
Col_1   Col_2   Col_3
aaa     dfd     ccc
sdf     jjj     sge
rty     fgh     rtg
hji     dfg     hyt
lkj     bgh     dcf
```

In each row, there is one element that is the same as one of the elements in the SECOND dataframe shown below (the elements in the second dataframe do not have to have any a specific order, of course).

```
list
ccc
sge
fgh
dfg
dcf
```

My goal is to iterate through each row in the FIRST dataframe and find that common element with the SECOND dataframe. This is followed by bringing that element ahead to the beginning of the row. The expected result is as follows:

Expected result

```
Col_1   Col_2   Col_3
ccc     aaa     dfd
sge     sdf     jjj
fgh     rty     rtg
dfg     hji     hyt
dcf     lkj     bgh
```

Any help will be appreciated !!

Comment: At first, i chose the solution given by @ Ben Dickson (below) as the best answer but then i found that it takes a long time for running for larger data

Comment: I tried to use a single list comprehension, my approach should be much faster. Check it and let me know!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not try using `apply`, `isin` and `tolist`:

```
print(df.apply(lambda x: x[x.isin(ls)].tolist() + x[~x.isin(ls)].tolist(), axis=1))
```

Output:

```
  col1 col2 col3
0  ccc  aaa  dfd
1  sge  sdf  jjj
2  fgh  rty  rtg
3  dfg  hji  hyt
4  dcf  lkj  bgh
```

I simple load each row and get the one that is in `ls` and make it the first value, by adding the rest to the end with itself being the first, using `isin` and `tolist` and `+`.

Comment: I like this solution. It is concise and elegant :)

Answer (score 3):

Using the [`.apply`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) method of the pandas DataFrame you can do it in one line. This will be faster than manually iterating over the rows.

It only uses pandas and works at a row level by first checking if any of the rows elements are in `ls`, sorts the returned binary indicator (True to front of row) and then re-indexes the row to be sorted in this order. It then broadcasts the results back onto the original row.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'col1':['aaa','sdf','rty','hji','lkj'],
                   'col2':['dfd','jjj','fgh','dfg','bgh'],
                   'col3':['ccc','sge','rtg','hyt','dcf']})     

ls = pd.Series(['ccc','sge','fgh','dfg','dcf'])

df = df.apply(lambda x: x[(~x.isin(ls)).argsort()], 
              axis=1, 
              result_type='broadcast')
```

Returns:

```
    col1  col2   col3
0   ccc    aaa   dfd
1   sge    sdf   jjj
2   fgh    rty   rtg
3   dfg    hji   hyt
4   dcf    lkj   bgh
```

Answer (score 1):

```
# turn 2nd dataframe into lookup list
lookup = df2['list'].tolist()

for index, row in df1.iterrows():
    # if column 1 matches do nothing
    # if column 2 matches list, reorder column 1 and 2, ignore 3
    if row['Col_2'] in lookup:
        col1 = row['Col_1']
        col2 = row['Col_2']
        df1.loc[index, 'Col_1'] = col2
        df1.loc[index, 'Col_2'] = col1
    # if column 3 matches, reorder values
    if row['Col_3'] in lookup:
        col1 = row['Col_1']
        col2 = row['Col_2']
        col3 = row['Col_3']
        df1.loc[index, 'Col_1'] = col3
        df1.loc[index, 'Col_2'] = col1
        df1.loc[index, 'Col_3'] = col2
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a possible solution using a list comprehension (`df1` and `df2` are the two DataFrames):

```
import pandas as pd

result = pd.DataFrame([((x,y,z) if x in set(df2.list)
                        else ((y,x,z) if y in set(df2.list)
                              else (z,x,y)))
                       for _, x, y, z in df1.itertuples()],
                      columns=df1.columns)
```

Comment: I am getting this error message: AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'list'. I am using python 2. Is it relaeted?

Comment: @Taie you can use `df2["list"]` instead

Comment: It is giving me this error message KeyError: 'list'

Comment: Does your `df2` dataframe have a column whose name is 'list'? I assumed so, as shown in your example. Also notice I have used `df2.list` two times

Answer (score 1):

Here's another solution that should be fast:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'col1':['aaa','sdf','rty','hji','lkj'],
                   'col2':['dfd','jjj','fgh','dfg','bgh'],
                   'col3':['ccc','sge','rtg','hyt','dcf']}) 
list2 = pd.DataFrame({'list':['ccc','sge','fgh','dfg','dcf']})

list2.assign(**df).unstack().drop_duplicates().groupby(level=1).agg(list).apply(pd.Series, index=[1,2,3]).add_prefix('col_')                                                                       

  col_1 col_2 col_3
0   ccc   aaa   dfd
1   sge   sdf   jjj
2   fgh   rty   rtg
3   dfg   hji   hyt
4   dcf   lkj   bgh
```

Comment: Hi. I am getting this error message: TypeError: 'type' object is not iterable. I am using python 2

Comment: I can't get pandas to work in python2 or I would try to help. I'll see if i can get a VM going to test it out

Comment: It works for me, but my speed tests show this is ~50% slower than using a single apply statement (as in my answer). I haven't tested how it scales though. It is also  fairly verbose!